# What are *L and *W used to denote in Optimality Theory

Tags: phonology, optimality-theory, notation

In certain papers on Optimality Theory (e.g. [this paper](http://works.bepress.com/john_j_mccarthy/29/) by McCarthy, or [this](http://www.linguisticsinamsterdam.nl/cgi/t/text/text-idx?c=aclc;sid=e08903bd79b52283508f08f7b5d46364;rgn=main;idno=m0302a02;view=text)) the tableaus contain the notations ***L** and ***W**, as seen in the image below:

[image]

What is meant by these notations? The second paper I linked to used these examples if you want to see the kinds of contexts they're used in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a tableau is comparing two candidates, a *W* indicates that the constraint in that column favors the winning candidate, while an *L* indicates that it favors the losing candidate.

In the example above, Candidate A is the loser and Candidate B is the winner. FAITH(Neg) favors the winner, since the winner violates it zero times and the loser violates it once. On the other hand, *Neg favors the loser, since the loser violates it once while the winner violates it twice.

See page 7, paragraph 3 of the McCarthy paper for further explanation.